# intellij: how to navigate to the file quickly in project tree that is in the editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation

intellij: how to navigate to the file quickly in project tree that is in the editor?

hot key or context-menu?

```
---project---      -------editor---
----               | file
  |---file         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the menu `Navigate | Select In...`<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and select `Project View` in the popup that appears. You can also assign a keyboard short cut to the `Select File in Project View` action, to get the same result in a single keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit escape anywhere to focus the editor

Comment: nothing happened.